# Select query based on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this select query to select specific event that happened 21 days ago:

```
select distinct 
    concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as Who,
    date_column 
from 
    database s
left join 
    person p on s.key = p.key
where
    type = 'granted' and 
    date_column < dateadd(day, -21, getdate()) and
    p.deleted = 0;
```

The query works by selecting all persons whom type was granted 21 days ago but I only need the names for the persons whom got access granted 21 days ago but did not use their card (Type = granted)

Basically only select name if the last time the Type column registered them as granted was 21 days ago and did not get access granted again within the 21 days period.

I hope this makes sense.

THANK YOU

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add this to the where clause:

```
and not exists(
    select * from database s2 
    where s2.key=s.key
      and s2.type = 'granted' and 
      s2.date_column > dateadd(day,-21,getdate()) 
  )
```

or change the query to this, which will give yo the most recent granted provided its more than 21 days ago. This is a slightly different result because you only get one row per user, but may give you what you want.

```
select  
  concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as Who,
  max(date_column) as date_Column
from database s
left join person p on s.key = p.key
where type = 'granted' and p.deleted = 0
group by firstname, lastname
having max(date_column) < dateadd(day,-21,getdate())
```

Comment: This worked better than my original one I will check the results of the query and I will mark the answer as right. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks this returned the right results. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the table called `database`, but if I understand correctly:

- That table contains the interactions/modifications to the card of a person.
- An interaction has a type, like 'granted' for the grant, or something else for other types of use.
- You want to include persons (and their date of granting), that were granted access within 21 days ago, and are not marked as deleted.
- But for those persons, no other interaction (any interaction of another type) should exist since granting.
- Persons should not be marked as deleted.

If so, then this should be the query:

```
select 
  concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as Who,
  date_column 
from 
  person p
  inner join database g on g.key = p.key
where
  -- Basic conditions which you already had
  g.type = 'granted' and
  g.date_column < dateadd(day,-21,getdate()) and
  p.deleted = 0 and
  -- Not exists a record for the same person, with a different 
  -- type and a date after the grant date
  not exists ( 
    select * 
    from database s 
    where 
      s.key = p.key and
      s.type <> 'granted' and
      s.date_column >= g.date_column
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for trying I understand it might be hard to understand I just can't share to much info.

Comment: If the deleted column = 0 is only a condition that have to be met. so if the person is still 0 and if they have not get access granted in the last 21 days I need to display their name.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select distinct 
    concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as Who,
    date_column 
from 
    database s
left join 
    person p on s.key = p.key
where
    type = 'granted' and 
    date_coumn between dateadd(date_column,-21,cast(getDate() as date)) AND  cast(getDate() as date)
    and p.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: This gave me the same results of my query above. Thanks though!